# Time data does not match format - ValueError

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I am trying to change string to datetime like below:

```
    max_datetime = datetime.strptime(max_date,'%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

However, I am getting the below-mentioned error:

> `ValueError: time data '2008-05-15 11:26:40' does not match format '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) of `datetime` tells that `%y` (with a lowercase y) represents a two-digit year, while from the error-message we can see that your input, `max_date` has a four-digit year. A four-digit year is represented by `%Y` (with an uppercase Y). So this is the source of your error. Since the rest looks fine,

```
max_datetime = datetime.strptime(max_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

should do the job.